# Open IntelliJ .idea Flex projects in Flash Builder

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, intellij-idea, flash-builder

I've seen quite a few posts about opening Flash Builder project files in IntelliJ but I haven't found any questions about going the other way.

Does anyone know if its feasible to open IntelliJ Flex projects inside of Flash Builder? Is there any kind of solution around that would allow for this workflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're out of luck: FlashBuilder can not import IntelliJ projects.
The only thing you can do, is creating a new project in FlashBuilder and point its `Project location` folder to the IntelliJ project folder.
Linking dependencies and setting source paths will have to be done manually. The main source folder of a FlashBuilder project is `/src` by default. So make sure to adjust that too if it was something like `src/main/flex` in your IntelliJ project.